# How To Auto Refresh content with templates

Tags: python, flask

I'm Trying to set up a Flask server that shows information about the PC. My issue is that I have the cpu usage and I want it to refresh on it’s own. Is there any way to do it without loading another page ? I've tried using jquery but It hasn’t been working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxyDm.jpg

My flask code:

```py
@app.route('/cpu')
def cpu():
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
    cpu = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand']
    cores = unicode(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
    return render_template('cpu.html', cpu = cpu, cores = cores, usage =usage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Have javascript refresh the page
- Or, make a second endpoint that returns the stats as json, then make an xhr request with javascript and update the data on the page

Comment: But if I'll use javascript isn't it going to refresh the whole page ? and if not can you give me an example please?

Comment: Yes, it will. If you don't want that, use the second method.

Comment: Thank you, i'm kind of a beginner can you show me an example on how to do that?

Comment: You really have to do it yourself if you want to understand how it works. I would start by reading how to make xhr requests with javascript. You mentioned you're using jquery, so here's a link to the docs explaining how to do that: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ But in short you will need a new route in flask returning jsonify(dict(cpu=cpu)), then make a get request to that route to get the data